# retain differents setInterval with a cookie or localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an automatic mouse with a time interval when I go inside a web. But I have a button that increase that speed but of course when I refresh the page or I go to other part of the web the speed is the first one. I tried with a cookie but I don't know how to do it because by default cookies or localstorage works only with names...

```
// Default speed
$(document).ready(function() {
  t = setInterval(clickbutton, 3000);
}

// Button
function aumentar() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  t = setInterval(clickbutton, 100);
}
```

I will be really grateful for your help because I'm going crazy.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're missing a `)` in the document.ready block. It's also not really clear what you're trying to do

Comment: So you set localstorage with a value and you read it. If the localstorage key does exist, you use your default.

Comment: You want to keep only the time or the entire variable

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I want to keep the speed, in this case de number 100. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> The `setTimeout()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.
>   The function is only executed once. If you need to repeat execution, use the `setInterval()` method.
>   Use the `clearTimeout()` method to prevent the function from running.

---

> The `setInterval()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
>   The `setInterval()` method will continue calling the function until `clearInterval()` is called, or the window is closed.

*HTML local storage; better than cookies.*

---

- Create a localStorage name/value pair with `localStorage.setItem("name", "value")`
- Retrieve the value of "name" and insert it into the element with `localStorage.getItem("name")`
- remove item `localStorage.removeItem("name")`

---

```
var t;
function speed(_speed, boo){
  if(boo){
    return localStorage.getItem("speed") || 3000;
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("speed", _speed);
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  t = setInterval(clickbutton, speed(true));
  // Button
  function aumentar() {
    clearInterval(t);
    speed(100);
    t = setInterval(clickbutton, 100);
  }
});
```